# Increasing text layer area size without changing font in Premiere Pro

Tags: premiere

I have created a text layer and inserted text as shown below.  When I try to show more of the text by grabbing the text area handles, the font size increases, which I don't want.  I am trying to create some rolling credits (position keyframes working fine), but cannot get the text box bigger when I add text - it gets truncated as shown in the pic.[image: Picture of truncated text in credit roll]
I'm clearly not looking up the right thing in google, as I get responses about expanding the text for titles.  Being new to Premiere / video editing, it could be I don't know the terminology, or just plain ignorance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a good question, and it's not obvious.

When you click once with the text tool, you make a single line of text.  If you drag the handles of this line, the text gets bigger and smaller.

But if you click and drag with the text tool instead to create your text, you get a text box.  Now resizing the box with the handles increases the amount of text in the box, not the font size.

Video (animated gif because of this website) below to demonstrate:

[image: clicking vs click and drag to make text]